How to ssh, su , maintain the session and make effects only to my session environment?
I want to SSH log in to a remote server (Amazon Linux 2) and simultaneously execute su and some commands and also maintain the SSH session in a single script like this:
ssh -t ec2-user@$host -i $keypath \
  'sudo -iu some-user bash -c "
   echo a; 
   c(){ clear; };
   echo b; 
   "'

output:
a
b
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.

So, a little improvement
ssh -t ec2-user@$host -i $keypath \
  'sudo -iu some-user bash -c "
   echo a; 
   c(){ clear; };
   echo b; 
   bash -l;
   echo c; 
   "'

output:
a
b  

(After this, I managed to SSH logged in to the remote as user: some-user and keep the session.)
However,
# on the remote
$ whoami
some-user
$ c  
bash: c: command not found  

I want to make c command work after I SSH logged in as user: some-user.
How can I fix this?
note:
1.
bash -l is to keep SSH session alive. If I remove it, I will be SSH logged out
2.
I don't want to edit any init file like ~/.bashrc  because I want to make effects only to my SSH session, not the others'.
3.
I can do alias c=clear after SSH logged in, yes, but it is bothering to do it if you want to set 10 aliases (of functions) and you have 10 different remotes.
4.
Remote shell is /bin/bash

I'm using sudo to avoid being asked for the password for some-user.

@tom you can use sudo -u some_user for that. See Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?

@terdon
Is this the one you intended? It didn't resolve my problem though. Let me know if I misinterpreted.
ssh -t ec2-user@$host -i $keypath 'sudo -u some-user -i bash -c "mkdir -p /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test ; echo THIS_IS_TEST ; bash -l ; alias c=clear; touch test-txt;"'

No, sorry, the sudo thing is just a minor improvement you can do to simplify the command, it won't solve your issue. However, is this really what you ran? When did you get the error? Your command would hang at bash -l and not do anything after that until you kill it with Ctrl+C, are you sure this is what you executed?

Yes, above one is the really what I ran. My command didn't hang at bash -l, which is written in order to maintain SSH session.(without this, I will be logged out from the remote server after mkdir,cd,echo). In addition, test-txt was created by touch commad at the time I executed the script. If I use sudo -u, the error message dissapears. Everything except that seems same to me.

That... doesn't make sense. Nothing after the bash -l would be executed until that exited and that won't exit, it will give you an interactive shell. Only after you exit that shell with exit or Ctrl+C will the rest of the commands be run. And none of what you describe should give an error about job control. Please simplify the command to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue. And what remote shell do you run on your AWS instance?

I edited the original question. Sorry to take your time. I hope this one make sense. If not, I will delete this question.

Please explain why you are not simply writing a script and why you need to do this in a non-interactive shell.

Because 1.I want to make effect only to my SSH session, not the others'. Writing and putting scripts to the remote or editing remote's init file is not what I want to do.
2.If you want to set 10 aliases to 10 different remotes in an interactive shell every single time after you SSH, that's bothering.

Please ask a new question and explain all this. Editing your .bashrc isn't relevant here but anyway would only affect your ssh session, no others. Same for the script. Ideally forget about any solution you have found but instead go back to the beginning and describe what you need, not the ways you have found to get part of what you need. See What is the XY problem?

Well... .bashrc is relevant here as it will afffect your SSH log in environment. I have no idea why you think so. I think what I want to do was stated clearly I want to make c command work after I SSH logged in as user: some-user. and also I don't understand why you think this is XY problem.  Anyways I will delete this question and create another one shortly.

Please don't delete, people have taken the time to answer. Just post a new one. And bashrc isn't relevant because it isn't read by non-interactive shells by default. See Run a command in an interactive shell with ssh after sourcing .bashrc (which is relevant to your question too). And when doing ssh you have a whole different set of things going on. And what we need to understand is why you want aliases. All of what you are trying to do here is very complicated and I don't think it is necessary at all

There's nothing in your example showing alias working or not working.  It probably actually is working, you just can't tell, and it isn't useful there anyway.
Alias is a shell built in command that sets a shell alias for the current shell.  It doesn't save that alias anywhere except in the memory of that shell.
If you start a new shell, it won't remember any aliases from other shell instances.  If you want to remember an alias across shells, the alias needs to be in one of the shell init files.
Worse, a command like this runs non-interactive, and many shell init files are structured to not bother loading aliases for non-interactive shells.  Also, which init files are loaded by the shell changes depending if this is a login shell or a subshell or a transitory non-iteractive shell.  Also, shell options can explicitly suppress loading init files.  So some care must be taken as to which shell init file the alias is created in if you want it to be available in non-interactive shells.
Adding sudo to this mix makes it even more confusing.  Did you want that alias in root's shell?  Then it needs to be in root's shell init files.
Presuming the linux default shell of bash for an interactive shell, aliases could go in ~/.bashrc for each user that wants to use the alias (including root).

Aliases are tricky. This is the relevant section of man bash (emphasis mine):

The  rules  concerning  the definition and use of aliases are
somewhat    confusing.  Bash always reads at least one complete line
of input, and    all lines that make up a compound command, before
executing any of the    commands on that line or the compound command.
Aliases  are  expanded    when  a command is read, not when it is
executed.  Therefore, an alias    definition appearing on the same
line as another command does not take    effect until the next line of
input is read.  The  commands  following    the  alias  definition on
that line are not affected by the new alias.    This behavior is also
an issue when functions are  executed.   Aliases    are expanded when
a function definition is read, not when the function    is  executed,
because a function definition is itself a command.  As a
consequence, aliases defined in a function are not available until af‐
ter that function is executed.  To be safe, always put  alias  defini‐
tions on a separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands.
For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell
functions.

What this means is that if you want to use aliases in a non-interactive shell as you are doing here, you need to explicitly enable aliases by using shopt -s expand_aliases and you need the alias definition to be on a separate line. A ; won't cut it, you need an actual line break:
## fails
$ ssh localhost 'alias ff="echo \"I am an alias!\""; ff'
bash: line 1: ff: command not found

## fails
$ ssh localhost 'alias ff="echo \"I am an alias!\""; shopt -s expand_aliases; ff'
bash: line 1: ff: command not found

## works
$ ssh localhost 'alias ff="echo \"I am an alias!\""; shopt -s expand_aliases; 
> ff'
I am an alias!

This... is really unlikely to be what you want. First, to be honest, it sounds like what you should be doing is putting all these commands into a script and running the script instead of fiddling about with this very complex approach. If you insist on doing it this way, then at least use a function instead of an alias:
$ ssh localhost 'ff(){ echo "I am a function!";}; ff'
I am a function!

See how much simpler that is?
Now, the error and behavior you describe don't match the command you have given us. However, to run the command you show, you would do something like this with a function:
ssh -t ec2-user@$host -i $keypath \
  'sudo -iu some-user bash -c "mkdir -p /tmp/test/; cd /tmp/test ; 
   echo THIS_IS_TEST; 
   c(){ clear; }
   touch test-txt; 
   c"'

Now this still doesn't make sense since clear doesn't make sense in this context, and I removed the bash -l since that just means you cannot do anything. I think you should probably ask a new question and explain what the end objective is here. It is extremely unlikely that any of this is the best way to do whatever it is you need to do, so if you ask a new question and give us the details, we should be able to provide a better approach.

I'm sorry I fail to tell you but it's important function or alias c works in an interactive shell after SSH logged in and switch user in the remote server (because I use it a lot but I don't want to write it to ~/.bashrc ).
In my env, if I remove bash -l part , I will get "Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed."

@tom please ask a new question. Explain what the end objective is and ask how to do it. I would bet you good money that whatever you want to do, running long single ssh commands as you are doing isn't the right approach. Why are you opening an interactive shell? If you do want an interactive shell, why not just run ssh and then work there?

I think you need to enable job control
#! /bin/bash
set -m
They should have enabled by default but somehow not and I don't really know why.

How would the OP do this? They are not running a script, so the shebang line (#!/bin/bash) seems odd. So where would the set -m fit in the command int he question? And how would it help since there is no history command there?

You should not be too quick to downvote others reply without doing thorough research or encouraging others to do the same. The documentation on AWS clearly mentions the steps how once can write a script. Sometimes one needs to write and run a small script  for automating a task or any other reason. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

I did not downvote since you already had one. Instead I took the time to explain the problem. Please read the question again, and then modify your answer to explain how this would be helpful. You linked to documentation about running scripts at launch time which doesn't seem relevant here. And you don't seem to have looked at the specific commands the OP is running.
